# System throws error builder cannot be resolved in the java program?

Tags: java

System throws error builder cannot be resolved in the java program:- in the lines **String result = builder.toString();** and  **builder.append("abc");**

```
   package newprojectstring;   
   import java.lang.StringBuilder;
    public class MyOwnClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Loop and append values.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 

    MyOwnClass Builder = new MyOwnClass(); 

      builder.append("abc");          
    }

    // Convert to string.

    String result = builder.toString();        
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

}

Comment: Did you change your code to `public class StringBuilder`? That is not what I mean. You should change `Stringbuilder builder = new Stringbuilder();` to `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: @Sweeper if i change Stringbuilder builder = new Stringbuilder(); to StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); system throws error in  String result = builder.toString();       line builder cannot be resolved

Comment: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();` should be outside of the loop since its not visible to outside.

Comment: @Satya yes it solved my prblm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, never name your own classes with names similar to the names of the classes from the standard `Java` libraries. If you do this, you will always get tons of errors and everyone who reads your code will curse you.

Next, you want to use the standard `StringBuilder` from the `java.lang` package, but actually you try to use an instance of your own `Stringbuilder` class that does not contain `append()` method. `StringBuilder` and `Stringbuilder` are different things, from the `Java`'s point of view. If you would not name your class `Stringbuilder`, you would see your mistake while you was writing it in your IDE.

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
public class MyOwnClass {       // *** Not 'Stringbuilder'!!!

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new StringBuilder
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // *** Not 'Stringbuilder' !!!

    // Loop and append values.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {   // Use spaces properly      
      builder.append("abc");          
    }

    // Convert to string.
    String result = builder.toString();        
    System.out.println(result);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `builder.append("abc");`, java is going to look for the `class` represented by reference named `builder` which in this case is your custom class `Stringbuilder`. Then it will look for a method `append` with a String argument, which it won't find, because you haven't defined a method like that.

Now there is a predefined `StringBuilder` which is having a method named `append`. I think you are confused with it. If you want to call the append method of StringBuilder you have to make a reference of `StringBuilder`.

```
Stringbuilder builder = new Stringbuilder();
builder.append("abc");
```